# How to use CakePHP 2 find in a hasMany association?

Tags: cakephp, search, find, relationship, has-many

I know this is an old quastion, but I just can't seem to make It work.

I have these relationships:
User hasMany Responsible
Responsible belongsTo User

I need, **through my User model**, perform a find like this:

```
$users = $this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Responsible.email' => $responsible_email));
```

But this won't work, It will throw a "Unknown column 'Responsible.email' in where clouse".

my real code is like this:

```
    $conditions = array();

    if (!empty($params['filter_by_name'])) {
        $conditions[] .= "LOWER(CONCAT(Profile.name, ' ', Profile.surname)) LIKE '%".$params['filter_by_name']."%'";
    }

    if (!empty($params['filter_by_email'])) {
        $conditions[] .= "LOWER(User.email) = '".$params['filter_by_email']."'";
    }

    if (!empty($params['filter_by_responsible_email'])) {
        $conditions[] .= "LOWER(Responsible.email) = '".$params['filter_by_responsible_email']."'";
    }

    $results = $this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions));
```

I have searched and tried in many ways, but I just can't make It work, how do I do this?

Edit:

I was able to do It with containable, but it also returns User with empty Responsible...

Comment: from what I remember you should be able to do a $this->User->Responsible->findAllByEmail($responsible_email); and you should get an answer with the Users in it

Comment: It should work if you set `$this->User->recursive = 1;` before the query, assuming that your associations are setup correctly, but it would probably be better to use containable.

Comment: @DavidGallagher It won't work because Cake doesn't do the Joins when you search in a hasMany relationships

Answer (score 1):

Got It:

```
       $options['joins'] = array(
            array(
                'table' => 'responsibles',
                'alias' => 'Responsible',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => array("User.id = Responsible.user_id")
            )
        );

        $conditions[] .= "Responsible.email = '".$params['filter_by_responsible_email']."'";

        $options['conditions'] = $conditions;

        $results = $this->User->find('all', $options);
```

Works well :)